# Docker images physical storage place

Tags: image, docker

Where can be images found in the filesystem? If I list all available images with `docker images` I see a size for every image. Are there single files with the given sizes in the filesystem or it is only estimated size of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot see individual image files on the file system.

They are stored in a large sparse image file in /var/lib/docker/devicemapper